# How to fix checkout onepage logo & black screen after display mini cart

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.2.6

I am using 2.2.6

Checkout onepage `LOGO` look like `css:z-index:1` & `black screen` after display mini cart.

How can i fix it?
i have tried to edit `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/estimation.html` `<button>` to `<a>` , but not working for me. please help!

[image]

Comment: It's hard to give you some solution with few informations and issue like this, maybe it's related to you theme ! can you share the url ?

Comment: Can i email message you,thank you @PRINCE